# How to access internal dictionary of collection.Counter to extend the functionality of Child class by using Inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance, python-collections

I want to add 2 functions in `collections.Counter` to add functionality to it for sorting and returning minimum `n` values. For this to work, I need to access the internal dictionary and I don't know how to use it. I checked the internal variables for the class created by using `vars(Counter)` and also the dunder and other function using `dir(Counter)`. As the dictonary us returned after creating the class so the method and variable is in the constructor itself. So to see the functionality I used `dir(Counter.__init__)` but could not find something good to use, as only methods were there.

For example if I do `counter = Counter(iterable)`, i need to access that `self.counter` variable **Inside** the class itself but I do not which variable that would be.

Below is the code I want to implement

```
from collections import Counter
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter


class CounterNew(Counter):
    '''
    Increase the functionality of collections.Counter() class
    '''
    def least_common(n:int)->list:
        '''
        Get the least common elements
        args:
            n: How many elements you want to have which have the lowest frequency
        out: list of tuples as [(key,frequency)]
        '''
        return heapq.nsmallest(n, counter.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
    
    
    def sort_by_freq(self,reverse:bool=False)->dict:
        '''
        Sort the Dictonary by frequency counts
        args:
            reverse: Whether to sort the dictonary in increasing or decreasing order
        out: Sorted dictonary
        '''
        self.sorted = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=reverse) # How can I sort the internal dictonary that is returned by class
        return self.sorted
```

Comment: The variable would be `self` (since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collections.Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. So it doesn't contain a dictionary in an instance variable, the dictionary is the instance itself. So if you need to access the dictionary, just use `self`.

You do the same thing in the `sort_by_freq` method. Since you want it to return a `dict`, you need to call `dict()` to convert it back into a dictionary.

```
def least_common(self, n:int)->list:
    return heapq.nsmallest(n, self.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])

def sort_by_freq(self,reverse:bool=False)->dict:
    '''
    Sort the Dictonary by frequency counts
    args:
        reverse: Whether to sort the dictonary in increasing or decreasing order
    out: Sorted dictonary
    '''
    self.sorted = dict(sorted(self.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=reverse))
    return self.sorted
```

Comment: Oh! That's something new. First time hearing that you can access `self` itself like this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what is I want to store the sorted dict? I mean how can I do it? Sort the internal dictionary?

Comment: The method definition is missing the `self` argument.

Comment: @ekhumoro Can you please explain it? Sorry I  did not get it. I mean is there any code I need to change?

Comment: @Deshwal `def least_common(self, n:int)->list:`.

Comment: @Deshwal All instance methods in a class need a `self` parameter.

Comment: @Deshwal Don't you access `self` like this in most class methods? What makes this case different?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to store the sorted dict in `self.sorted`.

Comment: @Barmar No actually this is what I am saying. This is what I have done `self.sorted` but it'll create a new internal `dict` object which is sorted. I want to sort the existing `self`. Is there any method to do this so when I do `print(vocab)`, it prints the sorted vocab itself instead of doing `vocab.sorted`

Comment: Dictionaries don't support reordering themselves. So you'd have to override the entire internal implementation of the dictionary.

Comment: Actually, I think you could empty the dictionary and then do `self.update(self.sorted)`

Comment: `self.clear()` then `self.update(self.sorted)`

Comment: The `Counter` class already has all this behaviour built-in. sorted by freq asc: `x.most_common()`; sorted by freq desc: `x.most_common()[::-1]`; least common N: `x.most_common()[:-N-1:-1]`.